# MergeSort in Java returning input

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

So I am to implement MergeSort using ArrayList(s).  This is my code but it is just returning what the user puts in.  The calling methods/classes are all correct as they were given.  It reads from a given text file then puts each line into a list and then passes in the list to this (my) MergeSort class.

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Merge12 implements Sort12
{
public  <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void  sort(List<T> list)
{
    if ( list == null )
         throw new NullPointerException("Null argument to sort");

    // Create the arrayList to insert into
    ArrayList<T> inputArray = new ArrayList<T>(list.size());
    ArrayList<T> tempArray = new ArrayList<T>(list.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        inputArray.add(list.get(i));
    int first = 0, last = inputArray.size()-1;

    internalMergeSort(inputArray, tempArray, first, last);
}
private  <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void 
    internalMergeSort(ArrayList<T> inputArray, ArrayList<T> tempArray,
                int first, int last)
{
    if( ( last - first + 1) <= 1)
        return;

    int mid = ( ( first + last + 1 ) / 2);
    internalMergeSort(inputArray, tempArray, first, mid - 1);
    internalMergeSort(inputArray, tempArray, mid, last);
    merge(inputArray, tempArray, first, mid, last);
} // internalMergeSort

private  <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void 
    merge(ArrayList<T> inputArray, ArrayList<T> tempArray,
                int first, int mid, int last)
{
    int insertIndex = first;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = mid;

    for(int i = 0, j = first; i < (index2 - first); i++, j++)
        tempArray.add(inputArray.get(j));

    while ((index1 < (mid - first)) && (index2 <= last)) {
        if(tempArray.get(index1).compareTo(inputArray.get(index2)) < 0) {
            inputArray.set(insertIndex, tempArray.get(index1));
            index1++;
        }
        else {
            inputArray.set(insertIndex, inputArray.get(index2));
            index2++;
        }
        insertIndex++;
    }

    while(index1 < (mid - first)) {
        inputArray.set(insertIndex, tempArray.get(index1));
        index1++;
        insertIndex++;
    }
} // Merge
}
// vim:ts=4:sw=4:sw=78
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code that modifies the List object that you pass in. You read the list and use it to create a new list that you then sort. if all of your sorting code works (I haven't checked) You can pass list to internalMergeSort and remove the code that generates inputArray

Comment: Thank you! Okay so I changed it to modify the contents of list to the sorted contents.  And they're like partly sorted with a lot of duplicates and I'm not sure why that is happening now.